# Using multiple sum case lines in query

Tags: sql

This code does exactly what I need it to do for the desired months. Basically provides `Numerator` and `Denominator`.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN smsdss.c_cfv_pas_fct_pt_acct_vst_all.vst_end_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' and             '2013-01-31'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Jan13,
SUM(CASE WHEN smsdss.c_cfv_pas_fct_pt_acct_vst_all.vst_end_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31' and [ind_ra_cfvmc_00-30] = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RA_Jan13,
SUM(CASE WHEN smsdss.c_cfv_pas_fct_pt_acct_vst_all.vst_end_date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' and '2013-02-28'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Feb13,
SUM(CASE WHEN smsdss.c_cfv_pas_fct_pt_acct_vst_all.vst_end_date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' and '2013-02-28' and [ind_ra_cfvmc_00-30] = 'YES'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RA_Feb13,
SUM(CASE WHEN smsdss.c_cfv_pas_fct_pt_acct_vst_all.vst_end_date BETWEEN '2013-03-01' and '2013-03-31'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Mar13,
```

It can get pretty tedious when you have multiple months...is there a more efficient way of performing this calculation?

THanks!

Comment: If you are going to ask about efficiency, you need to post the entire query, the table structure, and tag the question with the database you r using.  These are good ideas anyway, but performance is database-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group them by the year and month in a sub-select and then manipulate that:

```
SELECT DATEPART(year,  smsdss.c_cfv_pas_fct_pt_acct_vst_all.vst_end_date) AS TotalYear, 
       DATEPART(month,  smsdss.c_cfv_pas_fct_pt_acct_vst_all.vst_end_date) AS TotalMonth, 
       COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM [table]
GROUP BY DATEPART(year,  smsdss.c_cfv_pas_fct_pt_acct_vst_all.vst_end_date), 
       DATEPART(month,  smsdss.c_cfv_pas_fct_pt_acct_vst_all.vst_end_date)
```

and that would give you the totals by month, without having to specify the months beforehand.

Comment: Happy to help - I run into this situation in my reports all the time.